# Web Services for Android

Tags: java, android, json, web-services, soap

I am making an android application which have to get 1000 of records from server database. Can any one suggest me which web-service is recommended to fetch large data from Server.

1. SOAP
2. REST (JSON)
3. XML
4. or any other

I have experience of parsing of all these services, but didn't deal with that large amount of data ?
Which is fastest ? Suggestions please ?

Comment: This question, although not resolved, seems to have quite a selection of answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928033/how-to-improve-performance-for-android-ios-etc-to-consume-web-service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REST-JSON would be the better option, since browsers are inherently more adept with JSON
So I found this article... http://blog.feedly.com/2009/03/03/jsonrest-vs-xmlsoap/

And this SO article deals with the performance of JSON over XML
[Is parsing JSON faster than parsing XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596465/is-parsing-json-faster-than-parsing-xml)